# Silverlight multiple binding

Tags: silverlight, binding, telerik

I have a question about binding in silverlight. I made my class for Grid view data column:

```
public class NavigateItemID : GridViewDataColumn
{
    public Binding itemID { get; set; }
    public Binding usedType { get; set; }
}
```

And this is where I implement data column in xaml:

```
<ext:NavigateItemID UniqueName="objectName"
                    CellStyle="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridViewCellAlignmentToTop}}"
                    Width="0.3*"
                    Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource locResources}, Path=LabelsWrapper.lblObjectNameW}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding objectName}"
                    itemID="{Binding itemID}"
                    usedType="{Binding objectType}" />
```

I wanted to ask how can I get value of `itemID`?

Answer (score 0):

Used in this way, itemID will always be null.
The Binding class is a contruct which establishes a relationship between a property in the columns DataContext, and a dependency property on the target type.

In this case, assuming everything else is set up correctly, you must change the type of your properties for the Binding to work.

For Example:

```
public class NavigateItemID : GridViewDataColumn
{
    public int itemID
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(itemIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(itemIDProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty itemIDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("itemID", typeof(int), typeof(NavigateItemID), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public object usedType
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(usedTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(usedTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty usedTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("usedType", typeof(object), typeof(NavigateItemID), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

[Have a read of this for more on Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)